# iTunes library pointing to completely wrong files

Tags: itunes

Somewhere along the way, a significant portion of the songs in my iTunes library seem to be pointing to completely incorrect files (1640 of 9160, to be exact). I know there are tools and means for fixing files that are simply in a new/different folder and still have the same filename, but is there an easy/automated way to fix thousands of songs that are pointing to completely unrelated files?

Example from `iTunes Library.xml`:

```
    <dict>
        <key>Track ID</key><integer>13712</integer>
        <key>Name</key><string>Lover's Spit</string>
        <key>Artist</key><string>Broken Social Scene</string>
        <key>Album Artist</key><string>Broken Social Scene</string>
        <key>Album</key><string>You Forgot It In People</string>
        <key>Genre</key><string>Indie</string>
        <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
        <key>Size</key><integer>11613871</integer>
        <key>Total Time</key><integer>382302</integer>
        <key>Disc Number</key><integer>1</integer>
        <key>Disc Count</key><integer>1</integer>
        <key>Track Number</key><integer>11</integer>
        <key>Year</key><integer>2002</integer>
        <key>Date Modified</key><date>2012-07-25T18:48:35Z</date>
        <key>Date Added</key><date>2010-10-20T18:39:51Z</date>
        <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>241</integer>
        <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
        <key>Comments</key><string>Source: eMusic</string>
        <key>Play Count</key><integer>7</integer>
        <key>Play Date</key><integer>3427320429</integer>
        <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>2012-08-09T08:27:09Z</date>
        <key>Album Rating</key><integer>60</integer>
        <key>Album Rating Computed</key><true/>
        <key>Artwork Count</key><integer>1</integer>
        <key>Persistent ID</key><string>B664192E9854A1F1</string>
        <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
        <key>Location</key><string>file://localhost/Applications/_Productivity/Pages.app/Contents/Resources/Templates/Modern%20Photographer%20Invoice.template/Contents/Resources/zh_TW.lproj/</string>
        <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>10</integer>
        <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>3</integer>
    </dict>
```

Notice the `Location` node, in particular. It's pointing to a Pages template file rather than its MP3 file: `file:///Users/administrator/Music/Broken%20Social%20Scene/You%20Forgot%20It%20In%20People/11%20Lover's%20Spit.mp3`.

Not even close to what it should be!

I've already tried the following things, to no avail:

- **Re-add Music folder to library** — Unfortunately, this leaves me with duplicated entries. The broken item still remains, with play counts, ratings, etc. and the new item is started over from scratch. Not really ideal.
- **TuneUp and Rinse** — I tried running it through the trials of TuneUp and Rinse, which didn't seem to catch on to the problem I was having.

My last resort idea is to setup a script that parses the XML and checks for non MP3 `Location` strings. When one is found, attempt to re-construct the filename based on iTunes's automatic filenaming convention (e.g. *Lover's Spit* above becomes `11%20-%20Lover's%20Spit.mp3`. This likely would get me 90-95% there. The remaining items could be manually fixed.

Of course, that would involve a lot of scripting time and trial and error. I'm hoping there's a simpler solution to my problem.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a combination of your first and last ideas. You could re-add your Music folder to your library, and then use a script to change the location of the old entries (correct metadata) to the new entries (correct locations).

Pseudocode rough draft:

```
for every song in the XML file (seek)
  search the rest of the XML file for other songs of the same name
  if only one is found (found)
    log seek's name to file1
    if found is newer than seek
      copy found's Location value to seek
      remove found
    else
      copy seek's Location value to found
      remove seek
  else if more than one is found
    log seek's name to file2 (for manual editing)
  else (no others are found)
    log seek's name to file3
```

This script design would assuredly be quite inefficient, but it would fix most problems itself, and you would (er, should) only have to review the songs with more than 2 duplicate versions.

See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76576/how-do-i-correct-wrong-itunes-play-counts/77391#77391) for details on how to make these XML changes take effect on your library.

Comment: I wound up doing something fairly similar to this but ran into trouble applying my XML changes to my library. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Try moving all the files back to a case-insensitve drive.

This stumped me forever until I figured out the problem.  It wasn't until I started to manually correct the problem files that I noticed a common theme in the problem files.  "of" vs "Of".

Last year I migrated all my music from a case insensitive drive to a case sensitive drive.  Suddenly many of my songs would not play and point to completely different files on the drive, be it jpg images or whatever.

I had to write a script to compare the itunes xml to what was on the drive and figure out all the discrepancies.  Regardless...it is a bit of a time consuming nightmare to fix.

If you delete files out of your iTunes library and re-add them, DO NOT click "move to trash" otherwise it will delete whatever non-music file iTunes is pointing at. (!)

Answer (score 1):

And for you humans out there that don't write code...

This happens with movies as well.  Ex.  I play Lord of the Rings, I get The Martian.  Has gotten buggier and buggier since (not too soon) Tim Cook took over.  So now we pay Apple prices for Windows performance.  Thanks Obama...I digress.

Quick trick works for me.  Using the example above, intentionally play the movie that unintentionally ruins date night.  I.e.The Martian.  Close it.  Play the movie you want.  I.e. LOTR...and you, Sam and Frodo are reunited.  This works for me, and the other 95% of people that don't write scripts to listen to a song or play a movie.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error; for some reason, iTunes send me to a fonts folder when I ask it to "Show in Finder" the location of the song file.

I started experiencing this a few weeks ago when I attempted to sync an iPod before the external drive on which I store my iTunes library was ready.

The wrong files to which iTunes directs me are all on a different external drive (which I presume was connected when I attempted that unsuccessful sync).

I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Consider editing a question of you can make it better without changing it entirely. Otherwise, [ask]